# Run one test without transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, minitest, fixtures

I'd like to run one of the tests in our test suite without using the transactional tests strategy. I found I can do this by adding the following line to the top of the test:

```
self.use_transactional_tests = false
```

I'm worried this will leave my test database polluted unless I clean up any records created during the test.

- Is that assumption correct, or does rails use another cleanup strategy when you turn off the transactional strategy?
- If that's correct, what's the best way to clear out the whole database and load fixtures again after the test has run?

Comment: You can run your test and then check the database and you'll see if it gets polluted. The easiest way for me to clean the database and repopulate is to run `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:reset` it will drop everything, run migrations and seeds file and you'll have a clean db. I'm not sure why you don't want to use transactional tests though.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I think I'll need to do the cleanup manually but I'd rather find a faster solution than `rake db:reset`. We need to do this because the code under test includes transactions.

Comment: Usually, if you need to test something that has a transaction, the cleanest way to do that is to move the code that's inside the transaction to another method and test that method instead, that way you don't have to mess with cleaning the database yourself.